# How to UNION data without duplicates with respect to the key?

Tags: sql-server, key, unique, union, sql-server-2014

**Summary:** I need to union records of the same tables from databases named by years like `prefix_2012`, `prefix_2013`, `prefix_2014` -- without duplicities based on unique `id` key. The database-by-year is decided by third party, and I cannot change it.

Is it possible to define it as a view?

**Details:** Let the more detailed explanation of what I want is described using the following example. It returns all records, with all duplicities.

```
SELECT
    id,
    a,
    b
FROM prefix_2014.mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id,
    a,
    b
FROM prefix_2013.mytable
UNION ALL
    id,
    a,
    b
FROM prefix_2012.mytable
```

When replacing `UNION ALL` by `UNION` only, the identical records are merged. (That is only when values in all columns are the same. Am I right?)

**When the new-year** database is created, all *open* records are transfered from the last year, and the last year database content is *frozen*. The transfered records are initially duplicates in the technical sense (identical values in all columns). However, content of the transfered records with the same `id` may be changed later.

**Question:** Based on the unique `id`, how can I union the records from all of the year-based databases so that if the record comes from a later year, the previous years records are ignored as duplicities? Can this be done without explicit looping and without temporary tables? Can a view be written to do that?

Comment: Is the ID continuous between the tables? Are you just wanting unique a,b across these tables?

Comment: Only the ID is unique. The a and be may be changed. I need only the newest a, b. Not all ID's are copied to the new year.

Comment: Which database server are you using? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Microsoft SQL 2014.

Comment: It's good to use the tag for that. "SQL" does not mean "SQL Server". It means the SQL language.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I thought it can be fairly standard SQL solution.

Comment: I mean that the "SQL" tag is not for SQL Server alone. That tag is for the SQL language, across different database systems.

Comment: I understand you. I would like to understand how would it be done in principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have these tables and data, so this may need some work
First create a view of the IDs and years like so:

```
CREATE VIEW YearIDs AS  
SELECT ID, Max(year) FROM
(SELECT
    id, 2014 as year
FROM prefix_2014.mytable
UNION 
SELECT
    id, 2013
FROM prefix_2013.mytable
UNION 
    id, 2012
FROM prefix_2012.mytable)
GROUP By ID )
```

Now inner join to each select in your union:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.a, T1.b
FROM prefix_2014.mytable AS T1
INNER JOIN YearIDs AS Y1 ON Y1.Id = T1.ID AND Y1.year = 2014
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.id, T2.a, T2.b
FROM prefix_2013.mytable AS T2
INNER JOIN YearIDs AS Y2 ON Y2.Id = T2.ID AND Y2.year = 2013
UNION ALL
SELECT T3.id, T3.a, T3.b
FROM prefix_2012.mytable AS T3
INNER JOIN YearIDs AS Y3 ON Y3.Id = T3.ID AND Y3.year = 2012
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY ID` probably should not be followed by `)`. For Microsoft SQL 2014, there should be `AS t` before the `GROUP`. Otherwise, syntax error is reported.

Comment: Thanks for your help ;) I have finally ended with two views. The first one that extracts ids and max year, and the second one with the lower select.

Comment: @pepr You're right I'm sure but I dont have sql 2014 and didnt run the query as I dont have these tables. Just working from memory.

Comment: Well thank you :) I find in my current role a good imagination and sense of humour help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following;

```
  WITH CTE AS(SELECT
    id,
    3 as [Year]
FROM prefix_2014.mytable 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    id,
    2 as [Year]
FROM prefix_2013.mytable
UNION ALL
Select
    id,
    1 as [Year]
FROM prefix_2012.mytable)
Select  ID,MAX([Year]) as YR into #T From CTE
group by ID


Select t.ID,a,b From #T t
join Test1 t1
on t1.id = t.id
where YR = 1
UNION ALL   
Select t.ID,a,b From #T t
join Test2 t2
on t2.id = t.id
where YR = 2
UNION ALL   
Select t.ID,a,b From #T t
join Test3 t3
on t3.id = t.id
where YR = 3
```

This is the updated version. It is basically a different version of Kell's query

Comment: Hmm, not sure that this would work as the group by clause includes all three fields so you would get all non repeating data

Comment: If he wants to have the ID he can include the id, in his question, I think he is referring to all of the data. If the ID is not required then the id can simply be removed from the select and group by.

Comment: The `id` is unique, but `a` and `b` may be chanded. I need only the newest version of `a` and `b`. The `GROUP BY` would also require some grouping operation (like `SUM`...). Am I right?

Comment: If the ID is unique and you need the newest a and b for that unique id  then the query above should work.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath: I tried it with the real data. When 2014, 2013, and 2012 databases were unioned in that order, it did not remove duplicity for certain ID present only in 2012 and 2013, but not in 2014. Two rows were returned -- one from 2012 and one from 2013.

Comment: See the updated version. It is basically a different version of @Kell's query.